# Android Development/LibGDX no window opens when running

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx

I am trying to run LibGDX through Android Stuido, I have created a project, imported the project I generated in LibGDX, created a desktop launcher and made sure that my SDK is updated. When I hit run, it thinks for 2-5 seconds and then nothing happens, even the base "Badlogic" window doesn't open. I get a message saying Compilation completed successfully in 5s 585ms and it says "Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)"

I've tried a new project and uninstalling and reinstalling the whole thing, same issue.

Has anyone else come across this and a solution for it?

Comment: version and name of your graphics driver ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same error. Managed to fix it by rolling back my NVIDIA Driver to the previous version. I was on version 378.49 and switched back to 376.33 and now everything works fine. You can give that a try regardless of your graphics card.

Nvidia Geforce 378.57 Hot Fix Drivers:

- Fixed crash in Minecraft and some other Java-based titles

http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/geforce-378-57-hotfix-driver-download.html